# play video using opengles, android

Tags: android, opengl-es

how to play video using opengl es in android?

Answer (score 6):

Your question is a bit vague. If all you want to do is to play a video in a GL surface, it's possible. See the [`Media Player` sample code](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/MediaPlayerDemo_Video.html) that Dave was referring to in his sample. All you have to do there is to replace the `SurfaceView` with a `GLSurfaceView` in both the MediaPlayerDemo_Video.java file as well as in the corresponding layout file (mediaplayer_2.xml).

Also you need to create a custom Renderer class (one that implements the `GLSurfaceView.Renderer` interface) and set it to your `GLSurfaceView`.

After you do all this, you will have your video playing on a GL surface, but that would be all.

If, on the other hand, you want to manipulate the video, i.e. to draw the video frames in a GL texture and add effects to it or transform it (for example scale, rotate, etc.), then I'm afraid this can't be done. The reason is that you don't have access to the raw video frames in your application.

Comment: This was answered in Jan 5. Has "access to the raw video frames" changed? Can you be more specific about which line of code prevents this?

Comment: Hi Stelian. Scaling and rotating of video frames can be done using GLSurfaceView with OpenGLES2.0 code.Please check this    https://github.com/satish13131/Android_Programs/tree/master/graphics/opengl/video/surfaceview         You can apply scale and rotate operation on the mvp matrix and acheive the desirable result on the video

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you're metioning OpenGL here, but probably the easiest way to play video is using the [`VideoView` class](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html).  You'll want to have a look at the [`MediaPlayer` class](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) too.

You might find the [*Audio and Video* page in the Android Developer Documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/media/index.html#playback.html) helpful.

There's [`VideoView` sample code](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/VideoViewDemo.html) and [`MediaPlayer` sample code](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/MediaPlayerDemo_Video.html) in the API demos provided with the Android SDK.